# Why is my code failing to connect to a MongoDB database?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express

Im new to typescript and am trying to learn how to build a REST API. Im currently trying to connect to MongoDB but am confused on how to do so. Heres my code below, please comment with any solutions, thank you.

Here is where im connecting the database, using a config to pull data from my config folder.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import config from "config";

async function connect() {

    const dbUri = config.get<string>("dbUri")
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(dbUri);
        //conected through the config
        console.log("Connected to database");
    } catch {
        console.error("Failed to connect to database");
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

export default connect

export default {
    port: 1337,
    dbUri: "mongodb://localhost:27017.0.0.1/my_database"
}


import express from 'express';
import config from 'config'
import connect from './utils/connect';

const app = express();
const port = config.get<number>('port')

app.listen(port, async () => {
    console.log('App is Running');

    await connect()
})
```

Comment: your dbUri does not seem common to me

Comment: That dbUri looks like a typo, a combination of the default port (27017) and the localhost address (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Refer: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/connection-string/